# !important attribute in css being overridden by class with higher priority

Tags: html, css, python-sphinx

I have a sphinx based website and am using a plugin to display some text. I would like that text to be white, so I created an entry in the custom.css file, which has a lower priority than the css file being used by the extension. I added an !important attribute to override the color adjustment the extension would otherwise make. However, the color remains the same regardless of the css I added. This is how it looks in google inspect:

[image]

Is there a reason for this behavior? How do I get my class to override the attributes from the extension?

The html for this section looks as following:

```
<div class="card-header white-font docutils">
    <p class="card-text"><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong></p>
</div>
```

The class definitions in the css files are, for custom.css:

```
.white-font{
  color: rgb(255,255,255) !important;
}
```

and for the extension file:

```
p{
  margin-bottom:1.15rem;
  font-size:1em;
  color:rgba(var(--pst-color-paragraph),1)
}
```

Comment: The css files are very large and difficult to include, but I added the html structure so you may get a better idea

Comment: The !important is defined on the parent element, not on the `p` element. So it is normal behavior

Comment: Yes, exactly, what @GertB. said. Your _div_ element will have red text color here. But the paragraph has its _own_ color set. This has nothing to do with !important, or specificity.

Comment: Use `.white-font p { color: ...; }` - then this will apply to any p that is a descendant of `.white-font`. And since that rule has higher specificity, this doesn't even need !important.